# SharedArrayBuffer and SharedWorker

Tags: javascript, web, web-worker, ecmascript-2017

In the features of ECMAScript 2017 there is [Shared memory and atomics](http://2ality.com/2017/01/shared-array-buffer.html).
I try test it in Google Chrome 59.0.3071.109 (Experimental SharedArrayBuffer flag is enabled).
When I try post SharedArrayBuffer in simple Worker it's works. But when I try post SharedArrayBuffer in SharedWorker, in event parament of onmessage event handler I get event.data is null. Why is this so? Here is an example of my code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web Workers</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="post()">Post</button>
<button onclick="get()">Get</button>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
var worker = new SharedWorker('worker.js');
var buffer = new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
new Int32Array(buffer)[0] = 12;

function post() {
    worker.port.postMessage({buffer});
}

function get() {
    console.log(new Int32Array(buffer)[0]);
}
```

worker.js:

```
self.onconnect = function (e) {
    var [port] = e.ports;

    port.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e.data);// null
    };
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure how can you get that result but as far as I know, `SharedArrayBuffer` is still not yet supported on Chrome 59.

Comment: There is chrome://flags/#shared-array-buffer. 
I will repeat that everything is working with simple worker.

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/
Here it is also indicated.
[17] The feature have to be enabled via "Experimental enabled SharedArrayBuffer support in JavaScript." setting under about:flags

Comment: So there's reasons that this feature is still behind a flag. It's not yet stable. In this case, I think there's a bug with the current implementation on Chrome.

Comment: Ok. May be. When asking a question, I tried to understand this bug or feature. Thank you for your version.

Answer (score 2):

According Chromium [Blink Workers](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i3IA3TG00rpQ7MKlpNFYUF6EfLcV01_Cv3IYG_DjF7M/edit#heading=h.7smox3ra3f6n) Documention: **Shared Worker is Out-of-process.**

It run on another system process different to document process(which contain JS mainthread).

**Operation System process deny memory access from other process.**

`SharedArraybuffer` work by share(access) memory. So `SharedArraybuffer` create(access) by JS mainthread(document process) can't access by `Shared Worker`(Out-of-process).